# Changing the colour of a table cell

Tags: html, css, asp.net, html-table

I am using ASP.net to display data in a html table.

```
    <td>
       <div align="left" >
             <%= %TRIM(DLDPFS + ' ' + Status) %>
       </div>
    </td>
```

What I wanted was for if the value in status was to equal particular things, the box it is in should change color. But I am not sure if this is possible, as you cant really do much in the way of conditions with CSS.

So if status = 'low' make the cell red, high make the cell green etc.

Anyone got any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with JS & CSS.

JS:

```
var val = document.getElementsByTagName("td"),
    len = val.length;

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    var temp = val[i].innerText;

    if(temp > 0){
        val[i].innerHTML = '<span class="high">'+ temp +'</span>'
    } else {
        val[i].innerHTML = '<span class="low">'+ temp +'</span>'
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.high { color:green; }
.low { color:red; }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just put your status value into a class attribute, then add appropriate CSS.
E.g.

```
<td class = "<%= %TRIM(DLDPFS + ' ' + Status) %>">
       <div align="left" >
             <%= %TRIM(DLDPFS + ' ' + Status) %>
       </div>
    </td>
```

Css e.g.

```
.low {
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: In the CSS would I need <%= %TRIM(DLDPFS + ' ' + Status) %>.low or is it literally just .low?

Comment: You would need just ".low". Oops, and you need double quotes around the class attribute (so the html tag looks like  '<td class="low">'). Have just edited the answer accordingly